# SIP телефония

Tags: android, sip

Требуется сделать сип клиент под андроид, собственно стандартная библиотека не подходит по многим причинам, в т.ч. работа только на ОС 2.3+ и отсуствие некоторых функций.

Что можете посоветовать? Именно рабочие варианты? Есть ли варианты без НДК?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SipDroid](http://sipdroid.org/) - исходники открыты. Бери да пиши :)

Comment: Взял, написал

Comment: @AndroidDev У меня почему-то не удаеться скомпилировать, поделитесь оптыом?

Answer (score 0):

1. Самое простое что приходит на ум - это попробовать скомпилить исходники из-под 2.3 для более ранних версий - часто это срабатывает.
2. Варианты со [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457956/implemenation-of-sip-on-android-platform-2-1): [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) [jsip](http://jsip.java.net/).

Comment: Не прокатит, это же из АПИ андроида. + Функционала некоторого нету.

Comment: добавил в ответ